# Rename Images using Command line

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to rename 1000s of images.

What i am trying to do is rename the files and Append P before the extension Example

**SH10010.jpg** should be Renamed to **SH10010P.jpg**

What i tried us using

```
ren *.jpg *P.jpg
```

But it doesn't work, infact it adds extra P.jpg to the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out here is the answer if someone needs it

```
ren *.?* ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"P".*
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your system...

The perl rename command:

```
rename 's/(.*)P\.jpg/\1\.jpg/' *.jpg
```

The Unix rename command:

```
rename P '' SH{10000..11000}P.file
```